# How to prove continuity of addition over weird metric? Edit: Ignore this. Errors in the problem definition.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $f: R \times R \rightarrow R$ and let the metric over $R$ be $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and let the metric in $R \times R$ be $d_2((x,y),(a,b))= ((x-y)^2+(a-b)^2)^{1/2}$.

I believe I understand how to proceed to prove these types of things, in general, but I am having trouble with this one due to its troublesome metric.

It needs to be shown that for any $c=(a,b)$ in $R \times R$ and all $ \epsilon >0 $ there exists a $\delta$ such that for all $z=(x,y)$, $d_2(c,z) < \delta$ implies $d(b+a, x+y) < \epsilon$.

I know I should find that $|x+y-a-b| < ... < f( \delta , a,b)$ at which point I can choose $\delta$ to be sufficiently small to find $|x+y-a-b| < \epsilon$.

But I am having a difficult time using $d_2(z,c) < \delta$ to get something I can substitute in for the other inequality.

Could you help get me started?

Thanks.

Comment: If it proves too difficult use another metric, I think the sup-metric would be easier.

Comment: I think you mean $d_2((x,y),(a,b)) = ((x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a metric $d_2((1,1),(2,2))=0$

Comment: Thank you. I should have noticed earlier. Must be a misprint.